# r Shiny has to return user input into a conditionally built widget

Tags: r, shiny, conditional-statements

My tiny R Shiny app has two widgets. In the first one, the user selects what widget should show up as a 2nd widget. Then, the user provides input in the 2nd widget and the choices/entries provided in both widgets should be returned. 
However, for some reason, my app is not showing the user entry in my second widget.
Any advice?

Thank you very much!

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(dplyr)

# ________________________________________________________________________________________
# UI code ####

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(title = "Dynamic Widgets"),
  dashboardSidebar(
    # Radio button widget to select the 'type':
    radioButtons("type", label = h3("Pick widget type"), 
                 choices = list("Date" = 1, "Name" = 2)),
    # 2nd widget:
    uiOutput("ui_widget")
  ),
  dashboardBody( 
    fluidRow(
      # Just return what the user selected
      verbatimTextOutput("type_text"),
      verbatimTextOutput("widget_entry")
    )))

# ________________________________________________________________________________________
# SERVER code ####

server <- function(input, output) {

  ## Dynamic value for the second widget's input: ####
  widget2_input <- reactiveVal()

  ### 2nd widget to show - depending on the choice in the 1st widget  ####

  output$ui_widget <- renderUI({
    req(input$type)
    if (input$type == 1) {
      dateInput("mydate", label = h3("Enter Date"), value = "2020-01-23")
    } else {
      textInput("mytext", label = h3("Enter Name"), value = "Enter name...")
    }
  })

  ### Create verbatim text from widget type selection: ####
  output$type_text <- renderPrint({paste("Selected widget type is: ", input$type)})

  ### Create verbatim text from 2nd widget's selection: ####
  reactive({
    req(input$type)
    if (input$type == 1) {
      widget2_input <- paste("User entered date: ", as.character(input$mydate))
    } else {
      widget2_input <- paste("User entered name: ", input$mytext)
    }
    output$widget_entry <- renderPrint({ widget2_input })
  })
}

# ________________________________________________________________________________________
# Return a Shiny app object ####

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to get it done is to introduce an action button:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

# ________________________________________________________________________________________
# UI code ####

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(title = "Dynamic Widgets"),
  dashboardSidebar(
    # Radio button widget to select the 'type':
    radioButtons("type", label = h4("Pick widget type"), 
                 choices = list("Date" = 1, "Name" = 2)),
    # Widget to select the product:
    uiOutput("ui_widget"),
    # Confirm the entry:
    actionButton("confirm", label = "Confirm your Input")
  ),
  dashboardBody( 
    fluidRow(
      # Just return what the user selected
      verbatimTextOutput("type_text"),
      verbatimTextOutput("widget_entry")
    )))

# ________________________________________________________________________________________
# SERVER code ####

server <- function(input, output) {

  ## Dynamic value for the second widget's input: ####
  widget2_input <- reactiveVal()

  ### 2nd widget to show - depending on the choice in the 1st widget  ####

  output$ui_widget <- renderUI({
    req(input$type)
    if (input$type == 1) {
      dateInput("mydate", label = h4("Select a Date:"), value = "2020-01-23")
    } else {
      textInput("mytext", label = h4("Enter a Name:"), value = "Enter name...")
    }
  })

  ### Create verbatim text from widget type selection: ####
  output$type_text <- renderPrint({paste("Selected widget type is:", input$type)})

  ### Create verbatim text from 2nd widget's selection: ####
  observeEvent(input$confirm, {
    if (input$type == 1) {
      widget2_input <- paste("You entered a Date:", as.character(input$mydate))
    } else {
      widget2_input <- paste("You entered a Name:", input$mytext)
    }
    print(widget2_input)
    output$widget_entry <- renderPrint({ widget2_input })
  })
}

# ________________________________________________________________________________________
# Return a Shiny app object ####

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```